# Export plot for manipulation later

Tags: plotting, graphics, export

I'm looking for a remote machine to generate a `Plot`, and save the file so that I can import it and manipulate it as a standard Mathematica object later. How do you export the object as such? I can export to a PDF, but not to a data form where I can later import and manipulate.

A sketch of the workflow I would like: On remote machine:

```
plot = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, ImageSize -> Small];
Export["/path/file.ext", plot]
```

Transfer the file, then on local machine import and manipulate:

```
plot = Import["/path/file.ext"];
Show[plot, ImageSize -> Large]
```

I'm not looking to make a `Table` of values because I am leaving Mathematica to optimise the plot sampling (function evaluation is very expensive). I don't mind extracting the values it created in order to recreate the `Plot`, but I also don't know how to do that. Also, the remote machine is running in command-line mode.

Comment: Try using[`DumpSave`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DumpSave.html) and [`Get`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Get.html)

Comment: @m_goldberg, the `Get` call gives me `$Failed`. Both computers run Linux, but the remote machine has version 11, whereas the local has version 10.2, maybe that might be causing it?

Comment: Is there any way to get more information from the error?

Comment: My bad, `DumpSave` can be platform and version dependent. Mainly intended for use on a single machine, not for transferring objects between systems running different versions of Mathematica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
plot = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, ImageSize -> Small];

pts = Cases[plot, Line[pts_] :> pts, Infinity][[1]];

Export["pts.csv", pts];
```

At the second machine

```
pts2 = Import["pts.csv"];

ListLinePlot[pts2, ImageSize -> Large]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a multi-system environment to test this with, but you might try

```
Put[plot, FileNameJoin[{..., "plot.m"}]]
```

on one system and

```
Get[FileNameJoin[{..., "plot.m"}]]
```

You need to replace `...` with the proper network path for the file, of course.

Comment: Thanks for this. The `Put` command on the remote machine returns `Put::stream: -Graphics- is not a string, SocketObject, InputStream[ ], or
     OutputStream[ ].`

Comment: @bjorne. Don't `Put` directly to the remote machine. Have `Put` write to your local machine. Transfer the file to the remote machine with a system utility, and then do the `Get` on the remote machine from the transferred file.

Comment: That's what I was doing (but in the opposite direction, because I want the remote machine to do the heavy lifting, so it needs to do the `Put`). All Mathematica actions were local, and the file transfer was a system utility.